# Empty set - short questions regarding Empty set.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups

Please tell me which are true ( just made a few stuff for me to understand ):
**It is not homework**, its for me to understand a few stuff.

A) {$a,b$} = {$a,b,\emptyset$}
B) {$\emptyset$} = {} or $\emptyset$
C) Creating a group of {$a,b$} and adding {$\emptyset$} will be {$a,b$}
D) |{$a,b$}| = $2$
E) |{$a,b, \emptyset$}| = $3$ or $2$
F) |{$\emptyset, \emptyset$}| = $0$ or $2$
G) |{$a,b, \emptyset,$ {$\emptyset$}}| = $4$ or $2$

I keep making those mistakes every question and I want to know once and for all what happens when I add empty set to a group.

Comment: E is $3$. That should help you work out several of the others.

Comment: Assuming $a\neq b$: A and B are false. D is true. E is $3$, F is $1$, G is $4$. What do you mean with C?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks.

Comment: For what its worth, you should be careful to use the correct words in the correct scenarios.  You have used the words "*group*" and "*adding*" here when they shouldn't be.  Yes, *colloquially* you might refer to a collection of objects as a "group" of objects however in mathematics the word group has a very specific meaning that you don't intend here.  Similarly for "*adding*".  You should be using the words "*set*" and "*unioning*" or perhaps "*including*" here instead.

Comment: @Andreas Yea, a different than b. Regarding B, how is it false? I have a question that it is true to be honest.. that is why I was getting annoyed by B especially.
D yea I thought so, but wanted to make sure.
E Okay, now I understand.
F is 1? how, the power of empty team is 0, no? same as in G, that $\emptyset$ is empty team yea?
Regarding C: lets say I have a function:
f:{$(1,2), (2,6), (3,6), (4,8), (5,6)$} - and they ask the domain of each range. I need the domain of {$10$}, but we have only {$2,6,8$}, so we do $\emptyset$ but the problem is the answer is $\emptyset$ for it without {}

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh sorry, my english is not at its best, the question is in my launage(hebrew), I tried my best to write good at english here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty set is just as valid of an element of a set as any other potential element and exists *as an element* and increases the size just as any other element's inclusion would have caused.  Here, I assume $a$ and $b$ are different than eachother and different than $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$

- $\{a,b\}$ is not equal to $\{a,b,\emptyset\}$

The set on the left has two elements and the set on the right has three.  It does not matter than $\emptyset$ was the empty set here... it qualifies as the third element of the set $\{a,b,\emptyset\}$.  Remember, we are not "flattening" the set... we are looking at the set and asking what the top level things there are in it... in this case on the right there are three things... namely $a$ could be the "first" thing, $b$ the "second" thing, and $\emptyset$ the "third" thing.

- $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the same thing as $\emptyset$, and  $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the same thing as $\{\}$, but $\emptyset$ is the same thing as $\{\}$.

Here we have $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with one element inside of it... that element being the empty set.  Again to emphasize... the emptyset *is a perfectly valid object that exists*.  We do not use the symbol $\emptyset$ to represent the absence of something... we use it to represent *a set* who happens to have nothing included as elements.  Since $\{\emptyset\}$ has something inside of it (*that something being the emptyset*) this is different than $\emptyset$ which has nothing inside of it.  As a metaphor, this is like saying "A brown paper bag containing another smaller but empty plastic bag inside of it is different than a brown paper bag with nothing in it."  As for $\emptyset$ versus $\{\}$, those are equal by definition... they are just different notations for the same thing.

- $\{a,b\}\cup \emptyset$ is equal to $\{a,b\}$.  Meanwhile $\{a,b\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is equal to $\{a,b,\emptyset\}$.

If you union two sets together, the result is a set containing the full list of elements included in at least one of the two original sets.  In the first example no additional elements were included because $\emptyset$ was the set being unioned and it has no additional elements to include.  In the second example we need to include $\emptyset$ since the set being unioned was $\{\emptyset\}$ which does have an element inside of it... that element being $\emptyset$.

- $|\{a,b\}| = 2$

Yes, the two elements are $a$ and $b$

- $|\{a,b,\emptyset\}| = 3$

The three elements are $a,b$ and $\emptyset$ remembering that $\emptyset$ is a perfectly valid object to be considered an element.  It is not "invisible", it can not be pretended to not exist... it is a thing just like any other thing.

- $|\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}| = 1$

Again, the emptyset is perfectly valid as an object.  However, here having written the same object twice as an element is redundant.  Having written it twice does not make the set "have more of it" than before... "*Who is at the party?*"  "*Oh, well, John is here.  Also... John is here... or did I already say that?*"  The only person at the party that was mentioned is John.  Similarly, $\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}$ the only element named as an element of our set here is $\emptyset$.  It counts as an element of our set, but only can count once at a time.  Revisit this later when you talk about multisets.

- $|\{a,b,\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}| = 4$

This has four elements, namely $a$... $b$... $\emptyset$... and also $\{\emptyset\}$.  Note that $\emptyset$ is a perfectly valid element and that $\emptyset$ is not the same thing as $\{\emptyset\}$ so they each count as elements of the set and they each count as being different than each other.

Comment: Wow, huge thanks for the explanation, I will read it now and hope I will understand all!!

Comment: {∅} is not the same thing as ∅, and {∅} is not the same thing as {}, but ∅ is the same thing as {}........... About this, now I understand why my answer has $\emptyset$ instead of {}. so it is the same, thanks!!!

Comment: Wow, huge thanks again.
I read it all, and I actually understood it, you really made good explanations here. much appreciated.